# C# Validate DataSet filled with DGV data as XML

Tags: c#, xml, validation, datagridview, xsd

I want to make a "Save as" button which will validate data from dataGridView with .xsd XML schema before saving it as an XML file. The idea was to save DataTable filled with DGV data as an XML, validate it with .xsd and delete it if the file is valid but it's not possilbe as long as the file is in use. Please help.

```
private void saveAsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog win = new SaveFileDialog();
        win.InitialDirectory = "e:\\";
        win.Filter = "XML document (xml)|*.xml";
        if (win.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string file_name = win.FileName;

            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table = (DataTable) dataGridView1.DataSource;
            table.WriteXml(file_name);

            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.Schemas.Add(null, "e:/katalog.xsd");
            settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
            settings.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationEventHandler);
            XmlReader read = XmlReader.Create(file_name, settings);
            do
            {
                read.Read();
            }
            while (!f);

            if (!f)
            {
                File.Delete(file_name);
            }
            f = true;         
        }
    }

    static bool f = true;

    static void ValidationEventHandler(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Severity)
        {
            case XmlSeverityType.Error:
                Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e.Message);
                f = false;
                break;
            case XmlSeverityType.Warning:
                Console.WriteLine("Warning {0}", e.Message);
                f = false;
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where do `f` and `nazwa_pliku` come into existence?

Comment: I edited the code, it should be fine now. `f` is a static bool variable and `file_name` is a directory of a new file.

Comment: dziękuję, towarzysz!

Comment: I'm not sure if it is sarcasm or not, but I meant I edited it so it's more understandable. :P The code still doesn't work.

Comment: Ah, understood. No, it wasn't sarcasm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the question is why can't the file be deleted, it is because the XmlReader has the file open - call read.Close() before trying to delete the file.

Comment: I changed the             
`do
            {
                read.Read();
            }
            while (!f);

            if (!f)
            {
                File.Delete(file_name);
            }`
part to 
 `while(read.Read())
                {
                if (!f)
                    {
                        read.Close();
                        File.Delete(file_name);
                    }   
                }`
and it works, thank you.